# Django: is this possible to call view from template like ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django, python-3.x

I am working on Django framework. I am searching for function which call view from template.

In Asp.NET MVC we can call action(view) from view(template) in this way.

```
@Html.Action("Controller Name", "Action Name") or

@Html.Action("Action Name")
```

In simple words I want to get template html in other template.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def my_list(request):
    q = MyModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'mylist.html',{'my_list':q})
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

#want to call my_list view

</body>
</html>
```

**mylist.html**

```
<script>
    #lot of script here
</script>

{% for record in my_list %}
    <p>{{ record }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The solution which i have get from my search use html form or jquery post or get request.

my_list view contains queryset objects. I dont want call this query directly in index view. This is a partial view.

What are the solution are available for this type of issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable but seems like you are trying to reinvent [inclusion template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

```
@register.inclusion_tag('mylist.html')
def my_list():
    q = MyModel.objects.all()
    return {'my_list': q}
```

And then in `index.html`:

```
<html>
    {% load my_tags %}
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {% my_list %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh that is great. How i am silly! I have read this article but cannot understand the function :(

Comment: Just Two more things to ask. Javascript would also work properly when I get loaded html? and I want to override the parent page block tag. is this possible in my_list template? Thank you

Comment: The `mylist.html` template will be rendered and "pasted" as a string into `index.html`.  So your JS will work as if it be right in the `index.html`.

Comment: And you can't override parent page block of `index.html` from `mylist.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include` tag.
You can pass context to the template using `with` statement.
This isn't the same as `@Html.Action`, but it's quite similar.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include